# skip characters/numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, numbers, logic

How do I skip a number or a character same for two numbers or characters together or apart while those characters/numbers exist within a row of numbers or word

example (not lists):

I want to skip the number 3 (in any position) when I count from 2 to 14

the result would be

2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14

another would be skipping the number 31 in any combination where 3 and 1 come out as long as both exist

these two examples would apply for the characters also.

What I was doing was

```
for(int i = startingNum; i <= endingNum; i++){
    if(i "has a" 3){
        skip number;
    }
    else{
        counter++;
    }
}
```

combination of numbers

```
for(int i = startingNum; i <= endingNum; i++){
    if((i "has a" 3) AND (i "has a " 1)){
        skip number;
    }
    else{
        counter++;
    }
}
```

at the character one I'm completely lost...

Comment: `if(String.valueOf(yourInt).contains("3"))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to convert the number to a string and check if it contains that number as a substring:

```
for(int i = startingNum; i <= endingNum; i++) {
    if (!String.valueOf(i).contains("3")) { // Here
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches is using results of parsing, for example:

```
public static Integer isParsable(String text) {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(text);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return null;
  }
}

...
import java.io.IOException;

public class NumChecker {

    static String[] str = new String[]{"2", "4", "a", "sd", "d5", "6", "7", "8", "a1", "3", "10", "11", "12", "14"};
    static int startingNum = 2;
    static int endingNum = 10;
    static int counter = 0;
    static int mark = 3;

    public static Integer isParsable(String text) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(text);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i = startingNum; i <= endingNum; i++) {
            Integer num = isParsable(str[i]);
            if (num != null) {
                if (num == mark) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1
```